# Angular Multi-Slot Projection and Directives

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a tab menu where clicking on a tab (header) opens up some specific content. The way I would use this would be:

```
<dialog-menu>
  <dialog-menu-item>
    <div *appHeader>Test 1</div>
    <div *appContent>Content 1</div>
  </dialog-menu-item>
  <dialog-menu-item>
    <div *appHeader>Test 2</div>
    <div *appContent>Content 2</div>
  </dialog-menu-item>
</dialog-menu>
```

Where the dialog-menu-item has both the content for the header and the content. For simplicity I'd like to display the header and the content in separate divs, so my dialog-menu template is as follows:

dialog-menu.component.html

```
    <div>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
        <div>Header:</div>
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.header"></ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
        <div>Content:</div>
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.content"></ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
```

and the code for the directives, the dialog-menu, and dialog-menu-item is:

dialog-menu.component.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHeader]'
})
export class DialogMenuHeaderDirective {
  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>){}
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appContent]'
})
export class DialogMenuContentDirective {
  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>){}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-menu-item',
  template: "<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>"
})
export class DialogMenuItemComponent {
  @ContentChild(DialogMenuHeaderDirective) header: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild(DialogMenuContentDirective) content: TemplateRef<any>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-menu',
  templateUrl: './dialog-menu.component.html'
})
export class DialogMenuComponent {
  @ContentChildren(DialogMenuItemComponent) menuItems: QueryList<DialogMenuItemComponent>;
}
```

The for loops in the dialog-menu run, rendering the div containing "Content:" or "Header:", but the ngTemplateOutlet containers do not. I know it's probably something that needs to go in the template for dialog-menu-item, but haven't been able to figure that part out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess it should be `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="item.header">` or `<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.header">` but you seem to have mixed both together

Comment: @Pieterjan This didn't seem to change anything, maybe there are changes to the dialog-menu-item template that I'm missing. That component doesn't really need a template since I'm only using children from it, unfortunately that doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: Ah instead of using `ContentChild` you can try injecting the `DialogMenuItemComponent` into the `DialogMenuContentDirective` and `DialogMenuHeaderDirective`. Then store both templates on the itemcomponent. Use the constructor on the directives to assign them

Comment: A little [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/select2/src/directive/item-template.directive.ts#L10)

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting solution. I found that part of the problem with my code was having the type "TemplateRef" for header and content when they should have been of the directive type.